# Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5

Tags: java, maven, m2eclipse

Am getting following error.I have `jdk1.7.0_05`, `maven 3.0.5` and `eclipse juno`. what might be possible proble for this ?

`Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its
 dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.
 apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5: The repository system is of
 fline but the artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 i
 s not available in the local repository.`

Comment: Behind a proxy? Firewall?

Comment: how to check that ? am very new to this environment.

Answer (score 1):

Viewing this message in error: "The repository system is of fline"

It is possible that offline option has checked in eclipse preferences for Maven, check in window/preferences/maven.

Comment: i checked in preferences and its unchecked.

Comment: In the settings.xml configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

Click the update settings button on the windows-preferences-maven and after updating the proxies in settings.xml this may referesh your settings.